# How to deploy a python docker image to AWS Lambda?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, flask, aws-lambda

I am trying to figure out how to deploy a flask application that I have received with a `Dockerfile` to AWS Lambda.

In local, all I have to do to start the app is to enter `docker-compose up`. That's work great.

But I don't know how to deploy this environment to AWS Lambda and tell it to run `docker-compose up`to launch the app.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This is now possible -- see https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-for-aws-lambda-container-image-support/. This is a legitimate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to use a docker image with aws lambda. Lambda is supposed to execute function or code snippets in different possible programming languages.

You should use AWS ECS to run docker container from images.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-for-aws-lambda-container-image-support/
^ It is now possible